# catkin_make error

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, movegroup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to do trajectory planning for a robot arm and for that I have a cpp code. When I try to build it I receive an error.
I am using ROS Kinetic in Ubuntu 16.04. I am new to ROS and I would be grateful for the help.

Thanks in advance.

The error shown in the terminal is as follows:

```
Base path: /home/kashyap/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/kashyap/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/kashyap/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/kashyap/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j8 -l8" in "/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/build"
####
[ 66%] Built target media_files
[ 66%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_LaserScannerSignal
[ 66%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_BatteryState
[ 66%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_LaserTrajCmd
[ 66%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PressureState
[ 66%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_AccessPoint
[ 66%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_AccelerometerState
[ 66%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PeriodicCmd
[ 66%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_BatteryServer2
[ 66%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PowerState
[ 66%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_BatteryState2
[ 66%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_DashboardState
[ 66%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SetPeriodicCmd
[ 66%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SetLaserTrajCmd
[ 66%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PowerBoardState
[ 66%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_BatteryServer
[ 66%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 66%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 66%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 66%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 66%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 66%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 66%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 66%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GPUStatus
[ 66%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 66%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 66%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target set_pose1_cpp
[ 66%] Built target kinematic_model_tutorial
[ 67%] Built target ros_api_tutorial
[ 67%] Building CXX object igus_trajectory_planning_3/CMakeFiles/set_pose1_cpp.dir/src/set_pose1_cpp.cpp.o
[ 68%] Built target planning_scene_tutorial
[ 69%] Built target planning_scene_ros_api_tutorial
[ 69%] Built target planning_pipeline_tutorial
[ 70%] Built target motion_planning_api_tutorial
[ 70%] Built target move_group_interface_tutorial
[ 71%] Built target state_display_tutorial
[ 76%] Built target pr2_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 80%] Built target pr2_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 82%] Built target interactivity_tutorial
[ 87%] Built target pr2_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 88%] Built target pick_place_tutorial
[ 93%] Built target pr2_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 97%] Built target pr2_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 98%] Built target collision_contact_tutorial
[100%] Built target attached_body_tutorial
[100%] Built target pr2_msgs_generate_messages
/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/src/igus_trajectory_planning_3/src/set_pose1_cpp.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/src/igus_trajectory_planning_3/src/set_pose1_cpp.cpp:44:55: error: ‘move_group’ was not declared in this scope
 moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode success = move_group.plan(my_plan);
                                                       ^
/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/src/igus_trajectory_planning_3/src/set_pose1_cpp.cpp:44:71: error: ‘my_plan’ was not declared in this scope
 moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode success = move_group.plan(my_plan);
                                                                       ^
igus_trajectory_planning_3/CMakeFiles/set_pose1_cpp.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'igus_trajectory_planning_3/CMakeFiles/set_pose1_cpp.dir/src/set_pose1_cpp.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [igus_trajectory_planning_3/CMakeFiles/set_pose1_cpp.dir/src/set_pose1_cpp.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2591: recipe for target 'igus_trajectory_planning_3/CMakeFiles/set_pose1_cpp.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [igus_trajectory_planning_3/CMakeFiles/set_pose1_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

---

Edit: Hey, here's the CPP code

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "set_pose1_cpp");
    ros::NodeHandle node_handle;
    ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
    spinner.start();
    moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface group("igus");
    ros::Publisher display_publisher = node_handle.advertise<moveit_msgs::DisplayTrajectory>("/move_group/display_planned_path", 1, true);
    moveit_msgs::DisplayTrajectory display_trajectory;
    geometry_msgs::Pose target_pose1;
    target_pose1.orientation.w = 1.0;
    target_pose1.position.x = 0.28;
    target_pose1.position.y = -0.7;
    target_pose1.position.z = 1.0;
    group.setPoseTarget(target_pose1);
    moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode success = move_group.plan(my_plan);
    ROS_INFO_NAMED("igus_trajectory_planning_3", "Visualizing plan 1 (pose goal) %s", success == moveit_msgs::MoveItErrorCodes::SUCCESS ? "" : "FAILED"); 
    sleep(5.0);
    std::vector<double> group_variable_values;
    group.getCurrentState()->copyJointGroupPositions(group.getCurrentState()->getRobotModel()->getJointModelGroup(group.getName()), group_variable_values);
    sleep(5.0);
    ros::shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289585/catkin_make-error/) by [Kashyap.m94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33183/kashyap.m94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2018-04-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-04-25**:
Looks like a simple C++ error. If you can post your source code also we will be able to help you

**Comment by [Kashyap.m94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33183/kashyap.m94/) on 2018-04-26**:
Here's the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the error states, you haven't declared `move_group` or `my_plan`.  You do already have a `MoveGroupInterface` but you called it `group` (i.e., not `move_group`).  Just change the names to match.

As for the missing `my_plan`, you can put a line before the `move_group.plan(my_plan)` call like the following:
`moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan my_plan;`

You already probably found it but you can reference the tutorial [here](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/src/doc/move_group_interface_tutorial.html).  The full tutorial code for the MoveGroupInterface can be found [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_tutorials/blob/kinetic-devel/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/src/move_group_interface_tutorial.cpp).

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) with karma: 525 on 2018-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kashyap.m94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33183/kashyap.m94/) on 2018-04-26**:
Worked. Thanks for the help.